# How to convert an object of type String to Character?

Tags: java

I have a field that is of type String and I would like to convert it to Type, but I don't know how to do it.
Follow the code below:

```
public class InfoAccountMapper {
    public static InfoAccountEntity convert(AccountUniversal accountUniversal) {
        return InfoAccountEntity.builder()
                .codigoSegment(accountUniversal.getSegment())
                .build();
    }
```

I need to convert the object:

```
accountUniversal.getSegment()
```

I tried with `.charAt()` but it failed or I didn't know how to use it correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by *it failed* ? please be more precise, could you share the definition (first line) of the method `getSegment()` and the method `codigoSegment` ?

Comment: Note: We also don't know how to use your classes correctly with the context provided. But documention for usage of `charAt` is available elsewhere

Comment: I just need to convert `getSegment()` to Character. The use of `charAt` was just a guess.

Comment: For example, when using `toString()` to do a conversion.

Comment: Typically a String contains multiple characters, so I'm not understanding the context of this question. How do you expect to convert multiple characters in the String to a single Character object? We also have no idea what the AccountUniversal and InfoAccountEntity classes are. So if you are only dealing with a String class and a Character class what are the point of those two classes. You question need to be clarified.

Comment: The InfoAccountEntity class is converted to AccountUniversal, it is a DTO.
And in the InfoAccountEntity class, the `segment` field type is String and always receives 1 character, however when converting, I need this conversion from String to Character.

Comment: *I didn't know how to use it correctly.* - Did you specify the index? Post the code you actually used. The code you posted doesn't contain String or Character variables so we don't know what you are doing. We can't guess what you did. The API is should be self explanatory. If there is something about the API you don't understand then ask a question.  *field type is String and always receives 1 character* So then 1) get the String variable, 2) invoke `charAt(0)` to return the char. 3) use the char to create a `Character` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `toCharArray()` to get an Array of Chars